# oauth resource request to twitter

Tags: python, django, twitter, oauth

My ios client is using  to finish a login to Twitter Platform under OAuth. after a web login, the UIWebView is redirected to app server with a link like,

```
http://abc.com/accounts/twitter/login/callback/?oauth_token=yEkpImDMHPSMplt8mRjhM3XCVEHJtSPfKjRuU4D6Y&oauth_verifier=yFU1kplG2buSFN4jCt0WZuXJTA9roNTgBk9R4P8ec
```

which doesn't have oauth_token_secret.

I have implement other OAuth login like native facebook login. I can get access_token and access_secret from client and send to server (Python + Django), then server use these parameter to request basic user info from FB to finish the complete login flow.

Currently for twitter I only get oauth_token and oauth_verifier, can any one told me based on these two parameter, how to fetch info from Twitter API? Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to help without code-examples. This would help a lot attract more answers. Have you already looked at http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/? Looks very promising...

Comment: Facebook supports OAuth 2.0 where twitter supports OAuth 1.0